# If $x \equiv 23 \pmod{36}$, what is $x \bmod 9$ and why?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If $x \equiv 23 \pmod{36}$, what is $x \bmod 9$ and why? I got this question in school today. I know the answer is $5,$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: **Hint** $\ 9k\mid n\,\Rightarrow\, 9\mid n\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

====== Preface ======

In response to a comment by Bill Dubuque, I feel I must make it clear that $x \mod 9$  (or $x \pmod {9}$) is not a value as result of an operation, but a statement about how $x$ is related to some other number in terms of equivalence modulo $9$.

"What is $x \mod 9$" doesn't actually make any sense (although it is clear what you meant).  $x \equiv 23 \pmod{36}$ means that $x$ and $23$ are related in a certain way.  (Namely that $36| x- 23$).  It doesn't meant that there is some number equal to $23 \mod 36$ or a number equal to $x \mod 9$.

It is similar to saying $x < 23$ describes  a relationship between $x$ and $23$ (namely that $x$ is less than $23$).   It doesn't mean that there is a number equal to $< 23$ and $x$ is that number.

So in a way "What is  $x \mod 9$?" is a bit like saying "What is $x>$?"

What it should be is what number or numbers (there are more than one) is $x$ equivalent to modulo $9$.

Sorry for the pendantry.  But it is aan important (albeit subtle) distinction.

And now back to the answer:

=====================

Just do it:

$x \equiv 23 \pmod{36}$ means that there is an integer $k$ so that $x = 23 + 36k$

So $x = 23 + 9*(4k)$.  Which means $x \equiv 23 \pmod 9$. And that can be (is) our final answer.

We can *reduce* that further to $x \equiv 23 \equiv 5 \pmod 9$, if the question was going for an answer where $0 \le x < 9$ but the question doesn't *state* that that is a requirement. So any $x = 5 + 9j$ for an integer $j$ will be equally correct. So it's perfectly acceptable to say $x \equiv 23 \pmod 9$.

(When we noted $x = 23 + 9*(4k)$ we could take that further $x = 5 + 18 + 9*(4k) = 5 + 9*(4k + 2)$ so $x \equiv 5 \pmod 9$.

......

That's the answer... but there's more....

It should be clear:

Lemma: If $x \equiv a \pmod n$ and $m|n$, then $x \equiv a \pmod m$.

Pf:  $x\equiv a \pmod n \iff n|x-a$.  So if $m|n$ and $n|x-a$ then $m|n-a$ so $x \equiv a \pmod m$.  (But I think that proof is a little "cold" and distant and won't be as convincing to students and the argument above.  If $x \equiv a \pmod n$ then there is a $k$ so $x = a+k*n$.  But $m|n$ so there is a $j$ so that $n = m*j$ os $x = a + (jk)*m$.  So $x \equiv a \pmod m$.

......

Its important to notice it does *not* go in the reverse order:

If $x \equiv 5 \pmod 9$ it does not follow that $x \equiv 5 \pmod{36}$.  (After all $23 \equiv 5 \pmod 9$ but $23 \not \equiv 5 \pmod{36}\,.$)

That is if $x \equiv a \pmod m$ and $m|n$ it does *not* follow that $x\equiv a \pmod n$.

If $x \equiv a \pmod m$ then there is a $j$ so that $x = a + j*m$ and if $m|n$ there there is a $k$ so that $n = km$ so $x = a + j*\frac nk= a + \frac jk*n$ but we don't know that $\frac jk$ is an integer.

However we *do* know that $x \equiv a + j*m \pmod n$ for some integer $j$.

So if $x \equiv 5 \pmod 9$ then $x \equiv 5 + 9j \pmod{36}$ for some $j$.

Example: $5 \equiv 5 \pmod 9$ and $5 \equiv 5 + 9*0 \pmod{36}$.

And $14 \equiv 5 \pmod 9$ and $14 \equiv 5 + 9*1 \pmod{36}$.

And $23 \equiv 5 \pmod 9$ and $23 \equiv 5 + 9*2 \pmod{36}$.

Comment: Please use correct notation. What you wrote serves to *greatly* heighten the common confusion between mod as an operator vs. relation.

Comment: How so?  So far as I can tell I used the correct notation and made a point of stating that the $x \equiv 23 \mod 9$ and $x \equiv 5 \mod 9$ are both equivalent statements and that there isn't one single value.

Comment: I've seen in many textbooks $x \equiv 23 \mod 9$.  But you are correct that $(\mod 9)$ is better.  On the other hand I don't see how $(\mod 9)$ will avoid the operator vs. relation confusion.

Comment: Ye Gods.  That was a lot of tedious typing to do the edit  I hope I got them all.

Comment: The big havok wrecker in my opinion is the "$=$" rather than "$\equiv$".  And I for the very wording of this question "Than what is $x \mod 9$?" is already bogged down in the confusion.

Comment: I edited it to use \pmod  so you can see how it works (of course you can revert if you want). You should look up the difference between \mod, \bmod, \pmod

Comment: Oh, I wasn't familiar with that \pmod tag $\pmod n$ tag.  I suppose that is easier than the (\mod  ) .... except now I must put bracket around the argument.  Might be easier to just type (\mod)... sigh....

Comment: You can omit the brackets for single-char moduli. What textbooks do you refer to.

Comment: I was probably mistaken in the textbooks.  It was not impressed upon me that the parenthesis mattered so I didn't make any great effort to notice whether they were used or not (and of course many use entirely different notation such as $\equiv_9$ or some such.. which have some advantage to not weighting either side of the expression) and no-one (until you) had every corrected me.  I did not remember Niven and Zuckerman having used them but apparent they had (unless the universe changed in the last 30 minutes and put them in when they weren't there when I bought the book).

Comment: In more advanced contexts one can get away with such abuse because more advanced readers are far less likely to be confused by it. But one should be nicer to beginners.

Comment: Btw, you want $\ 23\bmod 6\ $ not $\ 23 \mod 6\ $  (the "b" means binary operator, and the "p" mean parens)

Comment: I'm still not sure that I see how parenthesis dissuade thinking in terms operators more than lack of parenthes. .... (also not sure what you mean by $23 \bmod 6$ vs. $23 \mod 6$.  Other than a spacing I don't see much of a difference in visual output or in concept.)

Comment: Just saw your last comment now. My experience is the paren's more strongly inhibit newbies from confusing the two, but the extra whitespace does not.  Btw, it's probably better not to add all that tangential stuff to the answer - maybe that's why it got a dv (not from me).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $x \equiv 23 \pmod{36}$ means that $(x-23)$ is a multiple of $36$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \equiv 23 \pmod{36}$ then $x = 36q+23 = 9(4q+2)+5 \equiv 5 \pmod{9}.$

Comment: It's important to note that there is more than one answer.  $x \equiv 5\mod 9$ is an answer but so is $x \equiv 14\mod 9$ and $x\equiv 32\mod 9$ etc.  The isn't asking you to solve for what $x$ *is* but just what is $x$ equivalent to $\mod 9$.  In fact we know for absolute certainty that $x$ *ISN"T* $5$.  $x$ could be $23$ or it could be $59$ or $95$.  But whatever it is it is $\equiv 5 \mod 9\equiv 14\mod 9\equiv 23 \mod 9\equiv 32 \mod 9\equiv 41 \mod 9\equiv .....$

Comment: I only partly agree with your observation. In fact I am **not** saying that $x$ is $5$. I am used to think that $x \equiv 5 \pmod{9}$ and $x \equiv 14 \pmod{9}$ are the same answer, because working in $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ you will have the class $[5]$ as representative for all numbers of the form $5+9j, j \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then I would say that $x \equiv 5 \pmod{9}$ or that $[x] = [5]$ in $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$, certainly not that $x=5$.

Comment: I didn't mean to add this as a comment to your answer but as a comment to the original post.  I'm sorry for the confusion.  I certainly agree with your comment.  I was just chewed out for faulty notation and that it might lead to thinking of $\mod$ as an operation.  So I think it is important that the OP get that we aren't solving for a value but finding a class of values.  But I meant that to be directed to the original question, not to your specific answer.

Comment: In the comments you are showing you care a lot about what the OP is asking. However, I think in your answer you are hiding the essential steps of the solution to this exercise behind a huge amount of technicalities and sofisticated arguments. They are unnecessarily long and hard to read, I actually do not see why the OP marked your answer as the correct one. To understand your point one can just read my comment above. Even some comments under your answer are unnecessary: you are just discussing with another user on something that the OP did not ask, and probably does not need.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the definitions. What does $x\equiv 23 \mod 36$ mean? It means that $(x-23)/36$ is an integer. So give that a name: $(x-23)/36=n\in \Bbb Z.$ So $x-23=36 n,$ so $x=23 +36 n=(9)(2+4n)+5.$ And $2+4n\in \Bbb Z$ because $n\in \Bbb Z$. Therefore $x$ is $5$ more than an integer-multiple of $9,$ so $x\equiv 5 \mod 9.$

BTW.If you asked me the Q in your title I could logically answer "It's $x$" because as stated it does't actually ask for a value from $0$ to $8$ even though we can presume that was the intent.